# Difficulty Understanding Javascript Code Snippet

Tags: javascript

I am trying to port some javascript to actionscript 3.  I am new to javascript, and whereas much of js is familiar, I am having a devil of a time deciphering some js code.  A global variable, "action", seems to be defined in a function prototype call, which is then apparently referenced later as a function parameter in the body of the script:

Variable "action" Definition:

```
function SteppedAction(proUpdater, unbrInterval, slInterval) {
}

SteppedAction.prototype.getResult = function 
    SteppedAction_getResult(recipient)
    {
    this.subactions.push({
        action: function(action)
        {
            // function body
        },
        prop: 0
    });
    return this;
};
```

In the body of the script, this same "action" seems to be referenced again in other functions, even though it appears to be defined as a function parameter itself in other anonymous functions and as an argument in the generatePl() function:

```
function generate () {
    activeAction = new SteppedAction(updateProgressUI)
        .executeSubaction(function(action) { ui.progressPanel.show(); }, 0)
        .executeSubaction(function(action) { generatePl(subdivs, 
        dist, count, rate, level, action); });
}
```

I am using Sublime Text to help decipher the javascript, and when I hover over any of the "action" named variables anywhere in the script, whether as function parameters or function call arguments, it references the original "action" in the definition given above.  I simply do not understand this.  How does a function parameter "know" it is referring to the original variable definition, unless function parameters in anonymous functions can somehow obtain global scope?  I do not use anonymous functions normally.

The code for the SteppedAction.executeSubaction() is:

```
SteppedAction.prototype.executeSubaction = function 
    SteppedAction_executeSubaction(subaction, proportion, name) {
    proportion = (typeof(proportion) === "number" && proportion >= 0) ? 
    proportion : 1;
    this.subactions.push({ action: subaction, proportion: proportion, 
    name: name });
    return this;
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"A global variable, "action", seems to be defined in a function prototype call, which is then apparently referenced later as a function parameter in the body of the script:"* I don't seen any global variable. Any occurrence of `action` in your examples is a function parameter and they have nothing to do with each other, except that all these functions are probably executed in the same way and are passed the same argument.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is that the variable name of a function declaration is independent of its surrounding body. The variable name will "shadow" any previously declared variable. For example:

```js
const action = "local variable";

const myFn = (action) => console.log("inside fn, action is", action);

myFn("other variable")
```

You'll notice that in this case, even though the `myFn` has a function argument of `action` it is completely independent of the `action` in the outer scope.

Similarly, it's important to note that `this.subactions` is storing a **function** as action, and not executing the action. Here's an example:

```js
const subactions = [];
const myFn = (action) => console.log("calling myFn with", action);

console.log("about to push subactions");
subactions.push({action: myFn});
console.log("action pushed");

console.log("calling myFn");
subactions[0].action("other variable");
```

Notice that, very similarly to the above, the `action` parameter of `myFn` isn't set until it's called, and it has nothing to do with the outer scope. I hope this clears up your questions.

### Addendum

I was putting together your code snippets and here's the ES2015 version of your code, if it helps. Hopefully the syntax is a bit more understandable.

```
class SteppedAction {
  constructor(proUpdater, unbrInterval, slInterval) {
    this.subactions = []; // missing but presumably exists
  }

  getResult(recipient) {
    this.subactions.push({
      action: (a) => {},
      prop: 0, // should this be proportion to match executeSubaction?
    });
    return this;
  }

  executeSubaction(subaction, proportion, name) {
    proportion = (typeof(proportion) === "number" && proportion >= 0) ? 
    proportion : 1;
    this.subactions.push({
      action: subaction,
      proportion: proportion,
      name: name
    });
    return this;
  }
}

const generate = () => {
  const activeAction = new SteppedAction();
  // ui is not defined here.
  activeAction.executeSubaction(() => ui.progressPanel.show(), 0);
  // several of these variables are not defined in the code snippet
  activeAction.executeSubaction((action) => generatePl(subdivs, dist, count, rate, level, action));
}
```

Comment: I would naturally understand your explanation to be the case, which is why I was confused when the Sublime Text text editor referenced the global "action" as the definition for the function parameter "action" AND the function argument "action." I was thinking that defining a global variable as an Object attribute in a function prototype definition somehow created a special type of variable that became some kind of universal namespace issue within the code. There are several other global variables where the text editor doesn't reference them in functions like it does the "action" variable.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's what I found out (at least how the Sublime Text text editor seems to work) through fiddling with the text editor:  when one defines a function at the global level, (named or assigned to a variable or object), that function is evidently assigned a namespace that is referenced within the rest of the program, including function parameter definitions and arguments.

Thus,

```
myArray.push(action: function(x){});

var action = function(x){};

function action(x){}
```

will all create a reference to themselves for future calls using the "action" identifier (including within function parameter signatures), so that the parameter, "action," in

```
var myFunction(action) {}
```

will reference all three of the function declarations above when the cursor is hovered over it, giving line numbers where each are defined/declared.  This only seems to happen with global function declarations.  Regular global variables with a single value ARE NOT referenced within function parameter signatures like function declarations are.

As long as this is a quirk in Sublime Text itself and not some strange convention in javascript, where global function declarations create a namespace issue within subsequent function parameter signatures, I can understand it, and ignore it in the future.  Thanks for the help!